# not returning error in else condition in php form while trying to return error when there is error

Tags: php, mysql, forms

*not returning empty errro in else condition when the username field is empty and inserting data in databse in if condition is working well but when i try to return an error the page goes blank*

```
    <?php include "db.php"?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
global $conn;
$error=array();
$username=$_POST['username'];

if($username==""){
             $error="username is empty";
}
 if(empty($error)){
 $sql="INSERT INTO users (username,password,category)VALUES('$username','$password','$category')";
 $res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 if($res){
     echo "done";
 }else{
     echo "try again";
 }
 }else{
    return $error;
 }
}



?>
<html>
<body>
<fieldset style="width:30%;">
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" id="username" ><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure, that `$username` really equals "", when nothing is entered? Since you didn't set `value=""` in the username input tag, it might be null or empty, which are different from `==""`.

Comment: yes username is empty when nothing is entered

Comment: echo once $username and check what is coming

Comment: tried using echo username in else when username is empty, form does not get executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found so many errors during execution please check the following code.

1) It should be `empty($username)` instead of `$username == ''` basically that doesn't matter, it will be work either of the methods

2) you have `return $error;` which means it will only return print nothing 
so you need to use `print_r($error)` there is no function to return so you can simply print that error on the top of the form.

3) use parameterize query instead of passing variables to query.

if still not working please uncomment that two lines just after php tag and check for the error

one more suggestion I have added for error you can display the errors just after the field like below

Please check for the `<span>` tag just added after `input` and style error class as you want like color border etc.

```
<?php 

    //error_reporting(-1);
    //ini_set('display_errors',true);
    include "db.php";

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        global $conn;
        $error=array();
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        if(empty($username)){
            $error['username']="username is empty";
        }
        if(empty($password)){
            $error['password']="password is empty";
        }

        if(empty($error)){
            $sql="INSERT INTO users (username,password,category)VALUES(?, ?, ?)";

            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
                $stmt->bind_param("sss", $username,$password,$category);
                if($stmt->execute())
                    echo "Done";
                else
                    echo "Try Again!";

            }
        } else {
            //print_r($error);
        }
    }

?>
<html>
    <body>
        <fieldset style="width:30%;">
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" id="username" ><br>
                <span class='error'><?=$error['username']?></span></br />
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" id="password" ><br>
                <span class='error'><?=$error['password']?></span></br />

                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: its working ,can you post  parameterize query of this code plz

Comment: updated the answer please check and let me know if any error

Comment: instead of  `$mysqli` you need to use `$conn` as you have defined `$conn` in your db.php

Comment: why you using 'sss' in this , $stmt->bind_param("sss", $username,$password,$category);

Comment: it is for string type check the link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: and where to use $conn exectly insted of mysqli

Comment: if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) i have used `$mysqli` it was an example your actual variable is $conn

Comment: so i have to use $conn insted of mysqli in if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql))

Comment: it should be `if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql))`

Comment: thank you for your suggestion and for error class too

Answer (score 0):

Try with this script.

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            global $conn;
            $error=array();
            $username=$_POST['username'];

            if($username == ""){
                $error="username is empty";
            }else{
             $sql="INSERT INTO users (username,password,category)VALUES('$username','$password','$category')";
             $res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
             if($res){
                 echo "done";
             }else{
                 echo "try again";
             }
            }
            //THIS IS ARRAY SO YOU HAAVE TO PRINT LIKE THIS
            print_r( $error);

        }
```

You don't have to need use else statement twice.just check whether error is empty or not and run.
 Happy Coding :-)

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\user_1.php on line 20
Array

Comment: See Update @luckyyadav

Comment: what if i have more than one field than i have to check for error in another if condition and to return error in else condition